# Calculating percentage change in pandas dataframe compared to baseline value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I'd like to calculate the percentage difference compared to the beginning value. Is there a way to use pct_change() to complete this task?

e.g

my data

```
 date         close
2020-05-08    100
2020-05-11    102
2020-05-12    108
```

I'd like the change to appear like

```
 date         close  change (%)
2020-05-08    100     0
2020-05-11    102     2
2020-05-12    108     8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
df['change'] = df['close'].div(df['close'].iloc[0]).sub(1).mul(100)
```

or

```
df['change'] = (df.close/df.close.iloc[0] - 1) * 100
```

Output:

```
         date  close  change
0  2020-05-08    100     0.0
1  2020-05-11    102     2.0
2  2020-05-12    108     8.0
```

Comment: The second looks like a better and concise solution. +1.

Comment: The second is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for your help!

Comment: It can be done with groupby? I have a DF with series of US market stocks and want to calculate the percentage change for each group based on the first day.

Comment: @interferemadly `(df['close']/df.groupby('ticker')['close'].transform('first') - 1) / 100`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done using `pct_change()`.

```
df['change'] = (df['close'].pct_change().fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().sub(1))*100
```

If you don't care about direction `(+/-)`, then you can also take the absolute value:

```
df['change'] = (df['close'].pct_change().fillna(0).add(1).cumprod().sub(1).abs())*100
```

Comment: lovely solution!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: as David suggested, there are better solutions than this. I will leave the answer so you guys and girls know what not to do :).

You can always use an extra column to help. It's fairly easy:

```
start_value = 100 #or access through the index

df['beginning'] = start_value
df['change (%)'] = 100 * (df.close/df.beginning - 1)
df
```

Output:

```
    date    close   beginning   change (%)
0   2020-05-08  100     100     0.0
1   2020-05-11  102     100     2.0
2   2020-05-12  108     100     8.0
```

Comment: Actually using an extra column makes it clearer I think, especially as you start to get more complicated problems (e.g. compare multiple rows against a single baseline, while still controlling against many other columns)